# array[i].querySelector is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm fairly new to puppeteer and I struggle to make it works.

I'm trying to loop over a list of links, here `linksList` and then select data in each links. But for some reasons I get this error.

```
for (let i = 0; i < linksList.length; i++) {
  await page.goto(linksList[i]);

  // récuperation des info.
  resultJob = await page.evaluate((linksList) => {
    let annonceDetail = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < linksList.length; i++) {
      let detail = linksList[i].querySelector('div[class="jobsearch-DesktopStickyContainer"]')

      annonceDetail.push({
        detail: detail
      });
    }

    return annonceDetail
  }, linksList)
```

When i **execute** the code
I have the error :

> linksList[i].querySelector is not a function

My `linkList` contains valid links. **Looping through an array with QuerySelector worked beforehand for me**, so I'm really lost here.

Here is the linksList code

```
linksList = await page.evaluate(() => {
            
                let links = []

                let card = document.querySelectorAll('div[class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard"]');

                
                for (let i = 0; i < card.length ; i++) {

                let linksDetail = card[i].querySelector('a[target="_blank"]').href
                
                
                // push les liens dans un tableau

                links.push(linksDetail)
    
             } 
            return links
            
            });
```

Comment: Where does `linksList` come from?

Comment: it comes from an other page.evaluate further up my code.  Links inside are valids

Comment: Can you show how it is declared/populated?

Comment: i just edited my post

Comment: `card[i].querySelector('a[target="_blank"]').href` returns a string, so your `linksList` is an array of strings. A string doesn't have a `querySelector` function. Did you intent to search inside this anchor tag (`'a[target="_blank"]'`)? Or did you intent to select the element from the page the link is referring to?

Comment: I intended to select some elements from the page the link is reffering to. So I should turn the array of string into an array of...something else ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Puppeteer, so can't help you much further, but yes those URL's need to be visited/fetched first before you can search their DOM.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to figure it out. Thank you for your help !